# ReactJs - xml to string converter

Tags: xml, reactjs

How to fetch and read xml file from local system in reactjs? 
i have tried with xml2js npm package but it dosent have xml read method.
Any help is appriciated Thank You

Comment: Just read the file as a string and pass it into `xml2js`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to read a local text file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14446447/how-to-read-a-local-text-file)

Comment: Synchronous XMLHttpRequest on the main thread is deprecated because of its detrimental effects to the end user's experience. For more help http://xhr.spec.whatwg.org/

Comment: above is the error i am getting when i am referening to the code in the above link

Comment: function readTextFile(file)
       {
           var rawFile = new XMLHttpRequest();
           rawFile.open("GET", file, false);
           rawFile.onreadystatechange = function ()
           {
               if(rawFile.readyState === 4)
               {
                   if(rawFile.status === 200 || rawFile.status == 0)
                   {
                       var allText = rawFile.responseText;                      
                   }
               }
           }
           rawFile.send(null);
       }
       readTextFile("file://D:/sb-code/config.xml");      
    }